# Is the following a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

[image: cauchy]

My working:

Fix epsilon>0. I need to show whether an N can be found such that

$|a_m - a_n| \lt \epsilon$ for all $m,n \ge N$

$|a_m - a_n| = |(-1)^m(2+1/m^2) - (-1)^n(2+1/n^2)|$

by taking m even, n odd (is this a good approach?) we get

$|4 + 1/m^2 + 1/n^2| \le |4+2/N^2|$

from here I'm not sure where to go.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Look at both $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ subsequences.

Comment: @mookid is that not what I did by taking m even and n even?

Comment: What I want to make you guess, is that this is *not* a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @mookid that's what I thought, I'm aware that I need to show it is bigger than epsilon, but I'm not sure what process to follow

Comment: simply proove that both sequences have different limits. This is not possible for a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Simply proove that both sequences have different limits. This is not possible for a Cauchy sequence.

Why? if $a_{2n}\to l_1$ and $a_{2n+1}\to l_2$m take $$\epsilon = \frac{|l_1 - l_2|}3$$

There is a $N$ such as $\forall n\ge N \  |a_{2n} - l_1| + |a_{2n+1} - l_2| < \epsilon$.

Then, for instance, $|a_{2n} - a_{2N+1}| \ge |l_1 - l_2| - (|a_{2n} - l_1| + |a_{2n+1} - l_2|)\ge \epsilon $.

Here, $a_{2n}\to 2$ and $a_{2n+1}\to -2$.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to look at the acumulation points, the sequence contains at  least two distinct limit points (acumulation points) $2$ and $-2$. Indeed $|a_{n}-2|\le 1/n^2$ when $n$ is even and $|a_{n}+2|\le 1/n^2$ when $n$ is odd. This shows that the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\mathbb{N} \rangle$ does not have a limit (why?).

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, no.  To verify, evaluate the limit of this sequence

Comment: $(a_{2k})=2+1/(2k)^2 \to 2 as  k \to \infty$.

$(a_{2k-1})=-2-1/(2k-1)^2 \to -2 as  k \to \infty$.

As sequences have different limits sequence not Cauchy. Is this correct?

Comment: This is a woefully incomplete answer and is also wrong. You cannot evaluate a limit in this case since no limit exists..